# Code for getting data from a API Rest with JWT (with Post and Get Method)

Tags: rest, api, jwt, powerquery, m

I'm stuck with my limited knowledge here, because i need to get access to the data from an Rest API with Json Web Token.

The data supplier send me 3 different url:

1. EndPoint of tokens : https://xxxxx.yyyyy.com/vftoken/oauth/token

with this parameters

UserName=vfrest&Password=t3sting&grant_type=password

the result must be a chain in format "JSON Array" with 3 fields:

a) access_token (dinamic value)

b) token_type

c) expires_in

2. Endpoint for test https://xxxxx.yyyyyy.com/vfrest/api/Prueba/Prueba2

a) KEY ="Autorization"

b) VALUE = Bearer "access_token"

c) Content-Type = application/x-www.form-urlencoded

3. Endpoint for data  https://xxxxx.yyyyy.com/vfrest/api/data
   the result must be a chain in format "JSON Array"

BUT... doesn't work with my poor programming skills

This is what we have right now:

[Our code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6upvu.png)

BUT we have this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQit7.png)

Comment: Luis, the challenge here is that you need to understand how OAuth and JWT works; also you need to make sure you understand the documentation right. You should try executing those requests with Postman or even with your code and capturing the responses so it's easier to see where the error is.

Comment: Hi @Davo, this is de code we write for now:

Comment: Hi @Luis, what do you get as response when you ask for the token in the 1st request?

Comment: Hi, it works from the PBI Desktop, but in the service have an error on credentials...

Comment: What's the error? If it works somewhere else then maybe you are passing the credentials in the wrong way. An API can require using headers while others can use Cookies or even request sending the data in the BODY of the request.

Comment: Failed to update data source credentials: Web.Contents failed to get contents from 'https://xxxx.yyyy.com/vftoken/oauth/token' (400): Bad Request

Comment: Luis, I'm not an expert in PBI at all, but just to understand; are you trying to conenct to an API based on PBI or just from PBI to a "normal" API?

Comment: Davo, PBI to "normal" API (im chilean too)

Comment: Buena Luis! Check this blog entry, it seems Web.Contents has some pitfalls. Try sending the params as shown here: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/08/16/using-the-relativepath-and-query-options-with-web-contents-in-power-query-and-power-bi-m-code/.

Also there's a big discusson about that problem here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/web-contents-with-specified-headers-works-in-PBI-desktop-but/td-p/22786/page/4